# changes package for peer reviewed journal: hide authors and convert 'replaced' to 'added'

Tags: macros, changes

I'm using the `changes` package to keep track of any changes I ( and my co-authors ) made for a peer reviewed journal. Meaning, in response to each of the reviewers' comments, we are using a new `author id` from the `changes` package to make it easier (for us) and the reviewer to find our additions and changes to a specific comment. But moreover, we also use a special `author id` to keep track of linguistic/grammar corrections we made.

1. But now, when submitting the revised journal, we would like to hide all linguistic/grammar corrections we made ( just show the 'final' state ) to avoid too much different colors and confusion. How I can 'toggle' the 'final' command for specific author id or achieve something similar?
2. Also I would like to replace **all** `\replaced` commands by `\added` to hide the crossed out text. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 1}, color=red]{r11}
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 2}, color=red]{r12}
\definechangesauthor[name={Language/Grammar}, color=black!50!green]{lang}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle all you have to do is redefine what the macros `\added` and `\replaced` does:

1. For this we create `\finalstate` that redefines `\added` and `\replaced` to be so-called "no-op"s. That is, they literally just gobble their arguments and spit out them out again.
2. Here we define `\convertreplaced` to transform `\replaced` to be equivalent to `\added`, dropping the replaced text.

You can issue the above commands anywhere in the document (or preamble), and subsequent setting of content will be updated accordingly. To that end, a "final state" document will be achieved when you issue `\finalstate` in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 1}, color=red]{r11}
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 2}, color=red]{r12}
\definechangesauthor[name={Language/Grammar}, color=black!50!green]{lang}

\newcommand{\finalstate}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\added}[2][]{##2}%
  \renewcommand{\replaced}[3][]{##2}}%
\newcommand{\convertreplaced}{%
  \renewcommand{\replaced}[3][]{\added[##1]{##2}}}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla}.

\convertreplaced

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla}.

\finalstate

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla}.

\end{document}
```

---

The following update adds functionality to manage a list of so-called "final state IDs":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{changes,etoolbox,xparse}

\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 1}, color=red]{r11}
\definechangesauthor[name={Reviewer 1. Comment 2}, color=red]{r12}
\definechangesauthor[name={Language/Grammar}, color=black!50!green]{lang}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\added}[2][\@empty]{%
  \setkeys{Changes@added}{#1}%
  \ifallfinal
    #2%
  \else
    \xifinlist{\Changes@added@id}{\finalstateids}{%
      #2%
    }{%
      \Changes@output%
        {\Changes@Markup@Added{#2}}%
        {#2}%
        {\Changes@added@id}%
        {\Changes@added@remark}%
        {#2}%
        {\changesaddname}%
    }%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{Changes@AddCount\Changes@added@id}%
}
\renewcommand{\deleted}[2][\@empty]{%
  \setkeys{Changes@deleted}{#1}%
  \ifallfinal\else% or \ifallfinal\unskip\else
    \xifinlist{\Changes@deleted@id}{\finalstateids}{}{% or \xifinlist{\Changes@deleted@id}{\finalstateids}{\unskip}{
      \Changes@output%
        {\Changes@Markup@Deleted{#2}}%
        {\@bsphack \expandafter \@esphack}%
        {\Changes@deleted@id}%
        {\Changes@deleted@remark}%
        {#2}%
        {\changesdeletename}%
    }%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{Changes@DeleteCount\Changes@deleted@id}%
}
\renewcommand{\replaced}[3][\@empty]{%
  \setkeys{Changes@replaced}{#1}%
  \ifallfinal
    #2%
  \else
    \xifinlist{\Changes@replaced@id}{\finalstateids}{%
      #2%
    }{%
      \Changes@output
        {{\Changes@Markup@Added{#2}}{\Changes@Markup@Deleted{#3}}}
        {#2}
        {\Changes@replaced@id}
        {\Changes@replaced@remark}%
        {#2}%
        {\changesreplacename}%
    }%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{Changes@ReplaceCount\Changes@replaced@id}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\finalstateids}{}
\newif\ifallfinal
\NewDocumentCommand{\finalstate}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\allfinaltrue}% All ids are in final state
    {\renewcommand{\do}[1]{\listgadd\finalstateids{##1}}% Add id to final state list
     \docsvlist{#1}}% Process list
}
\newcommand{\clearfinalstateids}{\renewcommand{\finalstateids}{}}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\finalstate[lang]|:\finalstate[lang]

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\finalstate[r12]|:\finalstate[r12]

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\clearfinalstateids\finalstate[r11,r12]|:\clearfinalstateids\finalstate[r11,r12]

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\finalstate[lang,r11]|:\finalstate[lang,r11]

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\clearfinalstateids|:\clearfinalstateids

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\bigskip\verb|\finalstate|:\finalstate

Bla bla bla \added[id=lang]{blubb} bla bla \replaced[id=r11]{addition}{Bla} bla bla \deleted[id=r12]{Bla}.

\end{document}
```

As a side-point, consider updating the `\deleted` macro to use `\unskip` rather than just printing nothing, as it will also attempt to remove the preceding space (see the comments above for placement).

Comment: Thanks for this! One question: the `finalstate` is now applied to all author ids, right? Is it possible to make it only for specific ones? e.g. `r11` in the example above?. Also it seems that the `finalstate` is actually reverting the old state, right? I was thinking of something like the `\usepackage[final]{changes}` switch for specific author ids.

Comment: @bonanza: Yes (I'll update this tomorrow). So you're interested in something like `\finalstate` (for all author ids), but `\finalstate[r11]` which will keep all other author ids' content in visible, but remove/finalize only author id `r11`'s content. I guess next thing you'll reach for the starts and want to enter something like `\finalstate[r11,r12,...]` where you supply a list of "finalized author ids". ;)